# How to communicate with Microsoft.Owin self hosted Web API from worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, synchronizationcontext

I'm looking for guidance on how to communicate with a Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp instance from another thread.

First I kick off the web server and the worker threads. I.e..

```
var app = WebApp.Start<WebServerConfig>("http://blahblah");
var worker = new WorkerClass();
worker.Start();
```

Now I want to execute some code when the worker thread detects an event. This code should run in the same thread as the web server and the same SynchronizationContext (the web app is completely single threaded and asynchronous). I want to handle these events in the same asynchronous manner as Web API requests, and be able to share data between them.

The problem is that 'app' above is just IDisposable. I have no way to access the SynchronizationContext of WebAPI requests. Is there a way to instantiate the web app differently?

Comment: Are you sure your web app is single-threaded? By default it's not. And I believe with self-hosting, you'd have to provide your own `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: I experimented. All controller actions block all others between awaits. They're all async. Though I'm new to this so I may have missed something.